# How do I change the global .NET system.net/mailSettings configuration?

Tags: asp.net, .net, iis

Can somebody tell me how to set the global `system.net/mailSettings` configuration in ASP.NET?

If I change it in the GUI of IIS Manager the file:

`C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\Config\web.config`

is changed.

Is there a way to access this file via the `Microsoft.Web.Administration` namespace?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got it:

```
System.Configuration.Configuration webconfig = System.Web.Configuration.WebConfigurationManager.OpenMachineConfiguration();
System.Net.Configuration.MailSettingsSectionGroup mailSection = webconfig.GetSectionGroup("system.net/mailSettings") as System.Net.Configuration.MailSettingsSectionGroup;
mailSection.Smtp.From = "aspx@defaultmail.com";
mailSection.Smtp.Network.Host = Service.Config.SMTP_SERVER;
mailSection.Smtp.Network.Port = Service.Config.SMTP_PORT;
webconfig.Save(System.Configuration.ConfigurationSaveMode.Modified);
```